# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure temp
is
  procedure sam
  is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line('This is from sample');
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('This is from test');
end;
/

begin
  temp;
end;
/
```

Comment: You have posted an error code (in the question title) and a snippet of code; however, you have not asked a question. Please edit your question to contain a question and some explanation of what you have tried to do to resolve it. Have you checked that there are no other objects called `temp`? Are you creating the procedure for the correct user? Have you tried changing the name of the procedure to something more descriptive of its function rather than just calling it `temp`?

Answer (score 3):

The error says that an object named `temp` already exisst, so you can not create another one.

For example, say you already have a table with that name:

```
SQL> create table temp (a number);

Table created.
```

If you try to build your procedure, you get:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure temp
  2  is
  3    procedure sam
  4    is
  5    begin
  6      dbms_output.put_line('This is from sample');
  7    end;
  8  begin
  9    dbms_output.put_line('This is from test');
 10  end;
 11  /
create or replace procedure temp
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

This is a way you can check the existence of such an object:

```
SQL> select object_type from obj where object_name = 'TEMP';

OBJECT_TYPE
-------------------
TABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

You use existing name for object(in your case this name is **temp**).
Change this name.

You can find object name by:

```
select * from USER_OBJECTS
where object_name = 'TEMP'
;
```